# R (tidyverse)- Columns sums for aggregated data for 2 categorical variables for Chi square test of independence?

Tags: r, dplyr

Could someone please kindly give me their advice?

1. I am looking to sum my column totals.
2. I need the frame for a Chi square test of independence, so if there is a faster way please enlighten me!

What is the best way to do this?

I tried with ColSums but it gave me an error (Error in colSums(., mpaa_rating, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1) : unused argument (mpaa_rating).
I was evidently not using it correctly or entering it at the right place. I tried: colSums (mpaa_rating, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1) %>%  just above spread.

Many thanks in advance,
Christine

```
rereprex::reprex_info() 
movie_help<- data.frame(tribble(
             ~mpaa_rating,                       ~genre,
                     "PG",         "Action & Adventure",
                      "R",         "Mystery & Suspense",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                     "PG",         "Action & Adventure",
                  "PG-13",                     "Comedy",
                      "R",                     "Comedy",
                      "R",         "Action & Adventure",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                      "G",                      "Drama",
                      "R",                     "Comedy",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                      "R",         "Mystery & Suspense",
                      "R",  "Musical & Performing Arts",
                "Unrated",                      "Drama",
                      "R",                      "Drama",
                  "PG-13",                      "Drama",
                  "PG-13",                      "Drama"
             )) 
movie_help %>% 
filter(!is.na(genre), !is.na(mpaa_rating)) %>% 
count(genre, mpaa_rating) %>%
group_by(genre) %>%
mutate(prop = n) %>%
mutate(Total= sum(n)) %>%
select(-n) %>%
spread(key = mpaa_rating, value = prop) 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#> # Groups:   genre [5]
#>                       genre Total     G    PG `PG-13`     R Unrated
#> *                     <chr> <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1        Action & Adventure     3    NA     2      NA     1      NA
#> 2                    Comedy     3    NA    NA       1     2      NA
#> 3                     Drama    11     1    NA       2     7       1
#> 4 Musical & Performing Arts     1    NA    NA      NA     1      NA
#> 5        Mystery & Suspense     2    NA    NA      NA     2      NA
```

Comment: are you possibly looking for the [`table`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html) function? (i.e. `chisq.test(table(movie_help))`)

Comment: excellent thank you @bouncyball. I am learning R and would like to be able to calculate it more manually too, would you happen to know how I get the sum total at the bottom too?

Comment: your post disappeared @bouncyball I just saw your solution for the totals at the bottom. I will try and see if I can find it again!!! thanks a lot

Comment: @bouncyball if you still have the code you posted for column totals I would be very keen on seeing it again. I am not getting the same degrees of freedom and your code might help me debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the sum at the bottom, I like to use the `janitor::adorn_totals` function from the janitor package. The janitor package has many little helper functions for situations where you want to clean tables in the way you want. Check more about it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/index.html). My favorite is also the `janitor::clean_names` which helps you sanitize column names uniformly.

Now in your case you can simply:

```
 movie_help %>% 
    filter(!is.na(genre), !is.na(mpaa_rating)) %>% 
    count(genre, mpaa_rating) %>% 
    group_by(genre) %>%
    mutate(prop = n) %>%
    mutate(Total= sum(n)) %>%  
    select(-n) %>%
    spread(key = mpaa_rating, value = prop, fill = 0) %>% 
    janitor::adorn_totals('row') %>% 
    janitor::clean_names()
```

Comment: thank you that was exactly what I needed!! Very nice.

Comment: Janitor is pipe compliant, so makes things easier.
One quick thing though. If you remove the character column genre, you can run the chisq.test on the data frame/tibble, but for some reason it messes up on the degrees of freedom calculation when compared to `chisq.test(table(movie_help))` . I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you so much for investigating. I would have no clue either, my uneducated guess would be something with NA. I will ask around or calculate manually so I know which answer is right.

Comment: I get it, when the summary is saved as a frame the totals are considered as columns so the degrees of freedom are 5*5 instead of 4*4

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` and `chisq.test` to perform the test you want:

```
chisq.test(table(movie_help))
```

We can also manually calculate the totals:

```
dat <- movie_help %>%
  filter(!is.na(genre),!is.na(mpaa_rating)) %>%
  count(genre, mpaa_rating) %>%
  group_by(genre) %>%
  mutate(prop = n) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(n)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(key = mpaa_rating, value = prop) 

bind_rows(dat, 
          cbind(data_frame('genre' = 'Total'), summarise_all(dat[,-1], sum, na.rm = T)))

  genre                     Total     G    PG `PG-13`     R Unrated
  <chr>                     <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int>   <int>
1 Action & Adventure            3    NA     2      NA     1      NA
2 Comedy                        3    NA    NA       1     2      NA
3 Drama                        11     1    NA       2     7       1
4 Musical & Performing Arts     1    NA    NA      NA     1      NA
5 Mystery & Suspense            2    NA    NA      NA     2      NA
6 Total                        20     1     2       3    13       1
```

Comment: Fantastic @bouncyball that is very useful to me.